# Problem with the animation of images after their creation

Tags: iphone, animation, timer, uiimageview

Hi every one here is my code :

```
-(void) onTimer {
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
[[self view] addSubview:imageView];

ix=imageView.center.x;
iy=imageView.center.y;

X=(240-ix)/230;
Y=(160-iy)/230;

}

-(void)onTimer2{
imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
```

}

"onTimer" is called every 4 seconds and there is a CADisplayLink (60fps) on "onTimer2".

My problem is that "imageView"'s animation stops every time "onTimer" is called; a new "imageView" is created then imageView move with "onTimer2" method then it stops and another "imageView" is created ...

What I want is that "imageView"'s animation continues and in parallel new "imageView"s are created, how can I do this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0):

You are using same `imageView` object to alloc and initialize every time. You need to use different `imageView`, like:

```
-(void) onTimer {
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abouffer_03.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:<specify desired frame>];
    imageView.image = image;
    [imageView setCenter:[self randomPointSquare]];
    [[self view] addSubview:imageView];

    ix=imageView.center.x;
    iy=imageView.center.y;

    X=(240-ix)/230;
    Y=(160-iy)/230;

}
```

Comment: No the problem is still here, the animation of imageView stop every 4 seconds

Comment: try using a different thread to add the subsequent imageViews

Comment: just try simple `[self performSelectorInBackground:]` method and pass ur onTimer as the selector.

Comment: yes but when I write this  [self performSelectorInBackground: onTimer]; I have a n error onTimer undeclared I don't know why

Comment: just check the definition of this function in documentation...you need to pass a selector object not a function name. use `@selector(onTimer)`. Getting help from documentation is pretty easy

Comment: I don't find many documentation but I have done this [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; and I receive signal SIGABRT with this

Comment: because this function does not exist. Its not a good idea to ignore warnings.

Comment: but what does [self performSelectorInBackground: ?

Comment: consult http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html